# Angular 7/Typescript : Create queue/array of methods

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a requirements that some functions should be called after some method completes execution.

Below is my code of processing the queue.

```
 processQueue() {
    while (this.queue.length) {
      var item = this.queue.shift();
      item.resolve(item.func(item.types));
    }
  }
```

This is one of the sample function to push method in queue

```
 getAllValues() {
    let promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.isReady) {
        resolve(this._getAllValues());
      } else {
        this.queue.push({
          resolve: resolve,
          func: this._getAllValues
        });
      }
    });
    return promise1;
  }
```

And this is one of the function which will be called on processing the queue

```
 _getAllValues() {
    var results = {}, values = this.enumInstance.enumsCache.values;
    for (var type in values) {
      if (values.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
        results[type] = values[type][this.enumInstance.lang];
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
```

The issue i am facing is when i call `_getAllValues()` directly then i am able to access `this.enumInstance`.
But when same method is being accessed through `processQueue()` i am unable to access `this.enumInstance`. It gives me `undefined`. I think `this` is not referred to main class in this case.

So can anyone help me here. How can i resolve this?

Comment: I fail to see how Angular is connected to this question.

Comment: you need to `bind` the function to the class instance `this._getAllValues.bind(this)`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks. You are lifesaver. I was stuck because of this.